# WPF MVVM: поиск и scroll в listview

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть `listview`. Он забайдин с `ObservableCollection<MyObject>`. Возможно ли организовать поиск "на лету" по коллекции с выделением найденного? Т.е. есть `TextBox` с триггером `EventName="TextChanged"` и при вводе туда символов, в `listview` отображать подходящие записи. Нашел [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341113/search-listview-items-using-textbox) вариант, но мне нужен MVVM.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Задача решается легко, кроме `Binding` ничего не требуется.
Разметка:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Pattern, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Margin="5,5,5,0" Padding="3"/>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _pattern;
    public string Pattern
    {
        get => _pattern;
        set
        {
            Set(ref _pattern, value);
            Selected = Strings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith(Pattern));
        }
    }

    string _selected;
    public string Selected
    {
        get => _selected;
        set => Set(ref _selected, value);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        Strings = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "Телевизор",
            "Телефон",
            "Кровать",
            "Чемодан",
            "Стол",
            "Шкаф",
            "Чайник"
        };
    }

    protected void Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        field = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Добавим скролл до выделенного Item.
Подпишемся на событие в разметке:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"
         SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"/>
```

Обработчик события в `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    listBox.ScrollIntoView(listBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здесь может быть маленькая проблема: когда элементов в списке будет достаточно много, то понадобится еще реализовать каким-то образом скролинг до выбранного элемента, сам то он автоматом не будет скролить на выбранный элемент.

Comment: @Bulson, представление представлением. Подпишемся на SelectionChanged и скроллим до выбранного. VM об этом думать не нужно.

Comment: Блеск, спасибо! А по SelectionChanged, это типа триггер вешать и скролить в самом LV? Или через команды?

Comment: @Rans, дополнил ответ