# Фильтрация datagrid по TextBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, filter, textbox

Использую WPF и MVVM паттерн Catel.
Имеется ObservableCollection в нее загружается данные с сервера с помощью Entity Framework Code First. Коллекцию привязываю к DataGrid, там же есть TextBox. Так вот нужно, чтобы по вводу в TextBox "OnTextFindChanged()" коллекция в DataGrid фильтровалась по введенному значению. Как это сделать именно на MVVM я не нашел,помогите куском кода плз.

Вот binding код для DataGrid и TextBox:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Students> DbStudents
    {
        get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<Students>>(DbStudentsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DbStudentsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData DbStudentsProperty = RegisterProperty("DbStudents",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<Students>));

    public string TextFind
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(TextFindProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextFindProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly PropertyData TextFindProperty = RegisterProperty("TextFind", typeof(string), null,
        (sender, e) => ((StudentsViewModel) sender).OnTextFindChanged());


    private void OnTextFindChanged()
    {
      //Здесь должна происходить фильтрация как я понимаю
    }
```

По кнопке загружаю в коллекцию данные с сервера:

```
    private TaskCommand _dbLoadedCommand;

    public TaskCommand DbLoadedCommand
    {
        get { return _dbLoadedCommand ?? (_dbLoadedCommand = new TaskCommand(DbLoaded, CanDbLoaded)); }
    }

    public Task DbLoaded()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

                _db.Students.Load();
                DbStudents = new ObservableCollection<Students>(_db.Students);

            }
        });
    }
    private bool CanDbLoaded()
    {
        if (DbStudents == null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Код привязки:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxFilter" Text="{Binding TextFind}"/>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DbStudents, Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=True}"><!-- остальной код--!></DataGrid>
```

Comment: Здесь посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/672416/218063

Comment: @Андрей К сожалению, это не то что нужно, мне именно поиск нужен, чтобы видны были только результаты.

Comment: вам нужно всего лишь вместо `FirstOrDefault()` использовать `Where()`

Comment: Ну типа `FilteredStudents = DbStudents.Where(...);` и привязываться к `FilteredStudents`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала необходимо описать два базовых интерфейса :

```
interface IFilter
{

    bool CanApply(object _obj);

    Predicate<object> Filter { get; }

    event FilterChangedEventHandler FilterChanged;
}

public delegate void FilterChangedEventHandler();
```

`IGridEntity` это интерфейс для абсолютно всех сущностей которые могут быть положены в гриду, если у вас есть универсальные фильтры - как фильтр по имени в гриде, то данный интерфейс обязан быть.

```
interface IGridEntity
{

    string FilteringString { get; }

}
```

`Human` - пример того что будет находится в гриде для фильтрования.

```
public class Human : IGridEntity
{
    private string m_name;
    private int m_age;

    public string FilteringString
    {
        get { return m_name; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_name; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return m_age; }
    }

    public Human(string _name, int _age)
    {
        m_name = _name;
        m_age = _age;
    }
}
```

И вот собственно пример фильтра.

```
public class TextFilter : IFilter
{
    public event FilterChangedEventHandler FilterChanged;

    private string m_filterString = string.Empty;

    public string FilterString
    {
        get { return m_filterString; }
        set
        {
            if (m_filterString != value)
            {
                m_filterString = value;
                if(FilterChanged != null)
                    FilterChanged.Invoke();
            } 
        }
    }

    public bool CanApply(object _obj)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m_filterString))
            return false;
        IGridEntity obj = _obj as IGridEntity;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public Predicate<object> Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return (o) =>
              {
                  if (CanApply(o))
                  {
                      IGridEntity human = o as IGridEntity;
                      if (human.FilteringString.Contains(m_filterString))
                          return true;
                      return false;
                  }
                  return true;

              };
        }
    }
}
```

Наша вьюмодель

```
public class DashBoardVM
{

    private readonly ObservableCollection<Human> m_humans = new ObservableCollection<Human>();

    public ListCollectionView Humans { get; set; }

    public TextFilter TextFilter { get; set; }

    public DashBoardVM()
    {
        TextFilter = new TextFilter();
        TextFilter.FilterChanged += TextFilterOnFilterChanged;
        m_humans.Add(new Human("Peter",23));
        m_humans.Add(new Human("Igor", 29));
        m_humans.Add(new Human("Sergey", 21));
        m_humans.Add(new Human("Zeliboba", 99));
        m_humans.Add(new Human("Jack", 11));
        m_humans.Add(new Human("Volodya", 34));
        Humans = new ListCollectionView(m_humans);
    }

    private void TextFilterOnFilterChanged()
    {
        Humans.Filter = TextFilter.Filter;
        Humans.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Всякий раз когда вы меняете что то в фильтре, фильтр пробрасывает евент, и `ListCollectionView` применяет его на себе. Если вы хотите делать мультифильтрование то советую написать какой нибудь класс `FilterAgregator`, который будет содержать `List<IFilter>` и по очереди, может даже по приоритету, применять их через предекат, `FilterAgregator` тоже наследуется от `IFIlter`.

Comment: вот это что за ужас? `IGridEntity obj = _obj as IGridEntity;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        return true;`

Comment: @Ev_Hyper Вы предлагаете использовать дженерики ? IFilter<in T> ?

Comment: нет, предлагаю нормально работать с типом `bool` а также использовать `is` вместо `as`. Тогда вся логика вашего метода `CanApply` займет одну строчку кода.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper ошибки и промахи у всех бывают ...

Comment: кто ж спорит :)

Comment: О, спасибо, все получилось:) @ParanoidPanda

Answer (score 1):

Я придумал решение(точнее начал импровизировать), оно скорее всего не совсем правильное, но для меня очень даже сойдет. Итак, может быть кому-нибудь пригодится.

```
public string TextFind // свойство которое привязываем к TextBox на View
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(TextFindProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextFindProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData TextFindProperty = RegisterProperty("TextFind", typeof(string), null,
        (sender, e) => ((DataGridStudentsViewModel) sender).OnTextFindChanged()); 


    private void OnTextFindChanged() //обрабатывем каждое изменение в свойстве
    {           
       DbStudents = new ObservableCollection<Students>(_db.Students.Where(s => s.FirstName.StartsWith(TextFind)));
       /*это строчка поиска, здесь DbStudents моя коллекция,
       _db - это мой контекст данных модели,
       Students - моя таблица,
       FirstName -это столбец, содерж. имена
       Недостаток в том, что при каждом изменение св-ва создается новая коллекция*/
    }
```

[image: Демонстрация]

Comment: Это примерно то, о чем я вам и писал. Зы. Обнулять перед присваиванием не нужно.

Comment: Обнуление убрал.Та я уже и сам додумался, не увидел, что вы написали. Спасибо за помощь, ваша статья направила мысли в нужное русло:) @Андрей

Comment: Почему бы не использовать ListCollectionView и не написать свой интерфейс IFIlter, который будет реализовывать любые вам необходимые фильтры, не только по имени/фамилии.

Comment: А есть  какой-нибудь пример? Ваш способ был бы более правильный. @ParanoidPanda