# Живой фильтр ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Имеется ObservableCollection. В нем лежат объекты с интерфейсом INotifyPropertyChanged. Объектов более 40т. Объект имеет порядка 30 полей. Имеется предикат, фильтр, который в себя берет объект и проходится по коллекции других предикатов (фильтров), которые в данный момент выбраны, это не главное.

В течении одной минуты, из вне, могут приходить изменения - от 100 до 2000 измененных объектов. Мой ObservableCollection лежит в ListCollectionView. Всякий раз когда приходят изменения делать Refresh() - жадно и медленно, и потом спадает после этого селект. Каким образом можно отслеживать только изменение одного объекта и применять только к нему предикат, а не делать рефреш всей коллекции. Проблема еще в том что все это пишется на .net 4.0

Моя VM:

```
public class TestVM : ViewModelBase
{
private Entity m_entity;

public Entity Entity
{
get{return m_entity;}
set
{
m_entity = value;
RaisePropertyChanged(string.Empty);
}
}

public string TestString
{
get{return m_entity.TestString;}
}
}
```

Comment: Что значит `отслеживать только изменение одного объекта` и `применять только к нему предикат`. Вас смущают постоянные события, которые вызывает коллекция, когда в ней что-то изменилось, например, добавилось 10 элементов, что породило за собой 10 событий об изменении?

Comment: Смысл в том что мне надо именно один единственный объект взять - который изменился, взять и по предикату понять - он у меня будет во View или нет.

Comment: Не совсем понятно: изменения происходят _внутри_ элементов? Тогда ObservableCollection и Refresh не важно, UI-элементы должны и так подхватывать изменения.

Comment: @VladD у меня ViewModel имеет просто холдер - объект из вне. а VM просто отдает его поля. Всякий раз когда приходят изменения - новый объект, я кладу его в холдер и делаю PropertyChanged(string.Empty). По логике я могу приатачиться к INotifyPropertyChanged смотреть что Property == string.Empty и уже дальше описывать логику. На моменте описания логики и ступор. Но скорее всего я иду не верным путем

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Нипанятна. А дайте пожалуйста код.

Comment: @VladD Пример фильтра - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678862/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-datagrid-%D0%BF%D0%BE-textbox/679459?noredirect=1#comment997077_679459

Моя реализация, в данный момент с ней работаю

Comment: @VladD ну и пример моей VM

Comment: Вы выставляете модельный объект для привязки? Эээ...

Comment: И почему не `RaisePropertyChanged("Entity");`, если уж так?

Comment: Ну и вы понимаете, что изменения внутри entity не будут видны, потому что Entity наверняка не реализует INPC?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63478/discussion-between-paranoidpanda-and-vladd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, предыдущее решение не подходит для .NET Framework 4.0
В этом случае, предлагаю вам реализовать собственную, максимально простую `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

На вход она будет принимать оригинальную `ObservableCollection<T> where T: INotifyPropertyChanged` и предикат `Func<T,bool>`, подписываться на изменения самой коллекции (добавление новых элементов) и на событие `PropertyChanged` каждого элемента.

Если элемент удаляется из оригинальной коллекции - вы перестаёте его возвращать (вероятно, у вас будет кэш в виде какой-то потокобезопасной коллекции - удаляем из него), отписываемся от `PropertyChanged`.

Если элемент добавляется в оригинальную коллекцию - запускается предикат. Если элемент соответсвует условию - сохраняем в локальный кэш и райсим собственное событие `CollectionChanged`.

Если райсистся `PropertyChanged`, прогоняем объект через фильтр. Если он перестал удовлетворять условию - удаляем из кэша и райсим собственное `CollectionChanged`.

Comment: Если уж реализовывать кастомную бизнес-логику, то может быть просто вот взять и реализовать её честно, в VM-классе, а не наследоваться? И пусть VM-класс выставляет два экземпляра `ObservableCollection` наружу. Так выглядит честнее.

Comment: не совсем понятно, что значит `райсистся`

Comment: производная от `raise`?

Comment: @FoggyFinder ага

Answer (score -1):

Автор, во-первых включи [виртуализацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx) для списка.

Во-вторых у `ListCollectionView` есть свойство [`IsLiveFiltering`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.islivefiltering(v=vs.110).aspx), включи его, [настрой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.livefilteringproperties(v=vs.110).aspx), и это должно решить твою проблему без необходимости вызова `Refresh`.

Comment: ...читаем по ссылке - доступно с .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: И спасибо за минус.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Эм? Какое отношение я имею к твоему минусу?