# WPF&MVVM: Описание логики Relay Command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

В [данном уроке](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.3.php) по паттерну `MVVM` для приложений `WPF` был такой пример:

```
private RelayCommand addCommand;
public RelayCommand AddCommand
{
    get
    {
        return addCommand ??
            (addCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
            {
                Phone phone = new Phone();
                Phones.Insert(0, phone);
                SelectedPhone = phone;
            }));
    }
}
```

Это команда на добавление нового объекта, находящаяся в `ApplicationViewModel`. Теперь мы можем привязать кнопке эту команду:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}">+</Button>
```

Одна из первых проблем, с которой я столкнулся при переписывании своего проекта в соответствии с шаблоном `MVVM` - это установка связи между командой `RelayCommand` и методом, где и описывается логика команды (впрочем, если это позволено и если логики мало, то можно и прямо внутри `RelayCommand` логику описать).

Вот конкретный **неработающий** пример. Метод `ToogleButton` должен изменяеть надпись на кнопке при нажатии на неё:

```
private void ToggleButton(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Button clickedButton = sender as Button;

    if (clickedButton.Tag.Equals("On")) {
        clickedButton.Content = "Off";
        clickedButton.Tag="Off";
    }
    else {
        clickedButton.Content = "On";
        clickedButton.Tag="Off";
    }
}
```

С событиями делалось всё просто и этот метод работал прекрасно, но в случае с `MVVM` событий принято избегать. Каким образом следует исправить приведённый ниже код, чтобы он заработал?

```
private RelayCommand clickButton;
public RelayCommand ClickButton {
    ToggleButton();
}

private void ToggleButton(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Button clickedButton = sender as Button;

    if (clickedButton.Tag.Equals("On")) {
        clickedButton.Content = "Off";
        clickedButton.Tag="Off";
    }
    else {
        clickedButton.Content = "On";
        clickedButton.Tag="Off";
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ClickButton}" Content="On" Tag="On" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я покажу как бы сделал это я.

Заведите в VM свойство для команды:

```
public ICommand OnCommand { get; }
```

Заведите свойство, которое будет отображать состояние (On/Of), например:

```
bool isOn;
public bool IsOn
{
    get => isOn;
    set 
    {
        isOn = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOn));
    }
}
```

Заведем метод, который будет переключать состояние:

```
void Switch()
{
    IsOn = !IsOn;
    // тут ваша логика
}
```

В конструкторе VM создадим команду:

```
public MainVm()
{
    OnCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => Switch());
}
```

Мне не нравится синтаксис типа:

```
private RelayCommand addCommand;
public RelayCommand AddCommand
{
    get
    {
        return addCommand ??
            (addCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
            {
                Phone phone = new Phone();
                Phones.Insert(0, phone);
                SelectedPhone = phone;
            }));
    }
}
```

Он слишком громоздок и избыточен

Теперь View-часть:

```
<Button Command="{Binding OnCommand}" Content="{Binding IsOn}"/>
```

Это уже работает, но текст на кнопке будет переключаться между False/True, давайте напишем конвертер, который будет выводить то что нужно нам:

```
class BoolToOnOffConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? "On" : "Off";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Привязка будет работать в одну сторону, поэтому я не реализовываю метод `ConvertBack`. Метод `Convert` получает в параметре bool-значение и возвращает строку, которую мы выведем на кнопке.

Добавим в разметку ресурс с конвертером:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToOnOffConverter x:Key="BoolToOnOffConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Теперь воспользуемся этим конвертером:

```
<Button Command="{Binding OnCommand}"
        Content="{Binding IsOn, Converter={StaticResource BoolToOnOffConverter}}"/>
```

Готово!

---

Ну и напоследок небольшая хитрость, позволяющая несколько разгрузить и упростить разметку.

Давайте уберем ресурс с конвертером, а сам конвертер определим как расширение разметки, нам потребуется добавить всего строчку кода, 90% которой нам сгенерирует студия:

```
class BoolToOnOffConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? "On" : "Off";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}
```

Отлично. Используем это так:

```
<Button Command="{Binding OnCommand}"
        Content="{Binding IsOn, Converter={local:BoolToOnOffConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Постараюсь применить его к своему случаю. Тут же возник ещё один небольшой вопрос: верно ли то, что в `MVVM` доступ к свойствам элементов управления довольно сложен (в отличие от событий, где есть доступ через параметры `object sender` и `EventArgs e`)?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, доступ из VM к контролам не нужен и вреден, так как нарушает паттерн и добавляет сильную связь между Vm и View, которую мы с помощью паттерна хотим избежать. А в задачах, которые касаются только отображения вы вправе обращаться к контролам так как удобнее, в том числе с помощью событий и behind-кода. Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/672432/218063 кому-то может не понравиться такой подход, но я считаю его вполне допустимым, а с точки зрения простоты - вообще лучшим.

Comment: Я вообще перешел на `MVVM` только потому, что там легко сделать управление сочетаниями клавиш (Вы же мне посоветовали это сделать в вопросе "Самый простой способ вызывать метод сочетанием клавиш"). Думал по незнанию: "Сейчас заменю все обработчики событий на команды - и готово". У меня в реальном примере не только надпись на кнопке, но внешний вид меняется, потому к нему нужен доступ. Но если я вернусь к обработчикам событий, тогда как им назначить сочетания клавиш? Дилемма? :)

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, ну так смотрите этот ответ, VM владеет свойством IsOn и меняет его, вьюшная часть привязывается к свойству и реагирует на него. Вот и привязывайте внешний вид к свойству. А вообще нужно больше подробностей чтобы определить что вам подойдет, это может быть триггер, например, или DataTemplateSelector

Comment: С другой стороны, если логика чисто вьюшная и не имеет никакого бекграунда в VM, то вы можете и команды свои разместить во View, в Code-behind, в принципе никто этого не запрещает

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, получилось у вас?

Comment: Я развернул [другое обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562318/wpfmvvm-access-to-controls-from-relaycommand) на англоязычном Stack Overflow xD

Comment: Ваше решение замечательно, но так как мой реальный проект гораздо сложнее, чем приведённый выше пример, то в ближайшее время не смогу Вас порадовать сообщением о том, что удачно применил полученные от Вас знания на практике.