# ScrollViewer В конец содержимого

Tags: c#, wpf

Приветствую!

На WPF странице есть `ScrollViewer` со множеством элементов. При открытии страницы  скрол находится вверху а можно ли (и если до то как) автоматически ставить положение полосы прокрутки вниз содержимого ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`ScrollToEnd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoend(v=vs.110).aspx) или [`ScrollToBottom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltobottom(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А это корректно с точки зрения MVVM ?

Comment: MVVM - это про то как правильно разделять ответственность классов, а не про то, что нельзя в CodeBehind. У вас чисто вьюшная задача, другим частям программы о которой вообще ничего знать не нужно, вот и пишите логику во View-части, например подпишитесь на событие Loaded окна. Вот пример такого разделения ответственностей: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/672432/218063

Comment: Благодарю! Так и сделаю